# how to access variables on same page in php

Tags: php

I want to access variable on same page but I can't .. my code is given below but the errors occurs Undefined index: cars

```
<form name="form1" action="#" method="post">
<select onChange="openOffersDialog(this.value);" name="cars" id="cars">  
  <option value="Volvo" id="Volvo">Volvo</option>        
  <option id="Saab" value="Saab" selected>Audi</option>                  
</select>
</form>
<?php $car = $_GET['cars'];
    switch ($car) { 
    case "Volvo": 
    echo  "<table width='50%' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td>Volvo1</td>
            <td>Volvo2</td>
          </tr>      
        </table>"; 
    break; 
    case "Saab": 
    echo  "<table width='50%' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td>Saab1</td>
            <td>Saab2</td>
          </tr>      
        </table>" ;
    break;
    default: 
    echo "Sorry,<br>";  
    } ?>
```

Comment: You're using POST instead of GET in the method. Also always check if a variable exists especially post/get : `$car = isset($_GET['cars']) ? $_GET['cars']: '';`

Comment: Why the downvotes? Problem was trivial, but legitimate. I know it’s Monday, but cheer up.

Comment: @JezenThomas That moment when such trivial questions get downvoted but the answers get upvoted, I feel sorry for the community ...

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV  I just tried as you suggested and also correct my mistake at <form method="post"> instead of post I set "get" ... still problem in unsolved ....!!

Comment: @ShilpaDeshmukh "problem unsolved" ? What does that mean ? Do you get an error ? empty page ? or "Sorry" ?

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV  Undefined index: cars

Comment: @ShilpaDeshmukh sorry but that's just impossible. Replace `$car = $_GET['cars'];` with my code above and make sure you're saving it and not loading from cache.

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV I have done same change as you suggested and I am sure that I saved my php page before executing ...and while refreshing page on browser I used ctrl+f5........... can I send you whole code because rest code is running properly just showing error here only

Comment: @ShilpaDeshmukh Ok, [try this](http://codepad.org/UEDA6bx8), I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much to help me I have send you code by e-mail

Comment: @ShilpaDeshmukh I'll maybe check it later ...

Answer (score 2):

You have three problems:

1. Your form is `method="post"` but you are trying to read data out of `$_GET`, change that to `$_POST` (or change the form to use `method="get"`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374/19068) for help determining which you should use).
2. You are trying to read data out of the form submission whether or not the form has actually been submitted. Test if the value exists with [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) before performing the rest of your logic that depends on it.
3. You have no submit button, so the form cannot be submitted. You might be expecting the PHP to run when the select is changed, but unless you have some JavaScript to trigger the form submission, that won't be the case.

Comment: I tried get and post both methods but still it not works

Comment: @ShilpaDeshmukh - After copy/pasting the code, changing `$_GET` to `$POST` and adding a submit button, it works for me.

Comment: I have make changes as you suggested '<form name="form1" action="#" method="get">

Comment: But there is no requirement of submit button the rest of code is working properly I can send whole code if you want to try it

Answer (score 0):

You have a `POST` method in your form. Replace `$_GET["cars"]` with `$_POST["cars"]`.

```
$car = $_POST['cars'];
```

Or, you need to change in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form name="form1" action="#" method="get">
```

And moreover, you should first check if the form has been posted. So you need to give  this upfront.

```
<?php if (count($_POST) && isset($_POST["cars"])) { ?>
```

And then you need to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have gone wrong is `$_GET`. Try `$_POST['cars'];` method. Please read the link below for more information

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: I have tried both methods but still it shows same error